# How to fix parse error when missing data from the input source in Alteryx?

Tags: sql, parsing, alteryx

I am quite new to data analytics, SQL and Alteryx. I have a workflow that is getting a parse error, because the fields are missing from the input source data. I need to add the rows in with no values to prevent the error. I'm wondering if adding a text input is the best way to add in missing rows? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: If there are fields missing, I assune you wish to add relevant columns, not rows. If so, create them using a Formula tool.

Comment: @johnjps111 I'm working with a workflow that was created by someone else. The records are transposed (Cross Tab) to columns, but the record that it is looking for further down the workflow is missing from the source data. I need to add the record before transposing.

Comment: if you are able to create the relevant row as a text input row, then yes, you can use a Union tool (https://help.alteryx.com/20213/designer/union-tool) to add that row to the rest of the workflow.